# Sass stuck on compiling @extend property inside loop but works with node-sass

Tags: css, sass, dart-sass

following code is using by `css-star-rating` library.

```scss
@for $i from $minRatingValue through $maxNumOfStars {
    &.value-#{$i}.half {

      .star-container {
        @if ($i < $maxNumOfStars) {
          .star:nth-child(#{$i+1}) {
            @extend .half;
          }
        }
      }

    }
  }
```

with following values for variables

```scss
$minRatingValue: 1 !default;
$maxNumOfStars: 6 !default;
```

Source: https://github.com/BioPhoton/css-star-rating/blob/master/src/scss/_modifiers.scss#L163

This part of code compile correctly using `node-sass` but not working as soon as i try to compile this with newer version of `sass` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass).
The compiler just stuck on and no error/warning is displayed. Any idea on how i can fix this?

I already tried the `!optional` flag but this doesnt affect the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from your `@extend`. Somehow, it seems that Node Sass and Dart Sass don't process it the same way. For example, with `$maxNumOfStars: 3`, the extended selector compiles as:

**Node Sass**

```
.half,
.rating.value-1.half .star-container .star:nth-child(2),
.rating.value-2.half .star-container .star:nth-child(3)
```

**Dart Sass**

```
.half,
.rating.value-2.half .star-container .star:nth-child(3),
.rating.value-1.half .star-container .rating.value-2.star:nth-child(2) .star-container .star:nth-child(3),
.rating.value-2.half .star-container .rating.value-1.star:nth-child(3) .star-container .star:nth-child(2),
.rating.value-1.half .star-container .star:nth-child(2)
```

The more loops you add, the more longer the selector is, which is probably what makes your compiler crash. The problem seems to be that the extended selector `.half` is also used on one of the parent `&.value-#{$i}.half`.

Though, I don't know if it is the intended behavior or a bug.

Depending on what selector you want in the end, you might need to rename some classes or use a [placeholder selector](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/placeholder-selectors) to fix the issue:

```
%half {
    // Code to extend
}

.half {
   @extend %half;
   ...
}

.rating {
    @for $i from $minRatingValue through $maxNumOfStars {
        &.value-#{$i} {
            .star-container {
                @if ($i < $maxNumOfStars) {
                    .star:nth-child(#{$i+1}) {
                         @extend %half;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was an intended behavior from the orignal developer. And I want to add a patch to fix this until i make a full refactoring of the legacy code.  How would you fix this using placeholder selectors?

Comment: @billyjov You want the same result as with Node Sass, right?

Comment: Exactly..Same result, but using Dart sass instead of node-sass

Comment: Thanks..I will give a try and let you know